# I got a JCache error in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have just installer Joomla and when I go to the page index at http://localhost/joomla16/administrator/index.php

I got like 100 lines of error of the following:

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla16\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 422

And this is repeated like thousand times!

Please help me I do not know what to do!
My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate.

Regards
Stefany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your php.ini file and search for error_reporting
set this to error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED